# Regular expression for searching IP addresses

Tags: regular-expression, search

I opened up a document in vim and I want to search the document for IP addresses. So I used this command

```
/[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}
```

But this pattern doesn't seem to return any of the IP addresses in my document. I can see there are IP addresses like `192.168.0.23` in  my document.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Vee has already given you the answer. I'd like to point out an equivalent but easier to type search pattern.

```
\v(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}
```

`\v` enables very-magic mode, which allows no escaping on `{()` characters, and `\d` is a digit.

Answer (score 6):

When trying to specify the number of matches to be 1 to 3 entries of the preceding sequence of numbers, the correct format is `\{m,n}`.

The manual reference is [here](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#pattern-overview).

Your example works when I change it to:

```
/[0-9]\{1,3}\.[0-9]\{1,3}\.[0-9]\{1,3}\.[0-9]\{1,3}
```

in my local test file.  However, the correct 0-255 ip address regex is

```
/\s\zs\(\(25[0-5]\|2[0-4]\d\|[01]\?\d\?\d\)\.\)\{3\}\(25[0-5]\|2[0-4]\d\|[01]\?\d\?\d\_s\)
```

which is explained in the updates.

### Edit

As pointed out in the comments, the `.` should be escaped to be `\.` to match it explicitly, otherwise you are able to get other non-ip address matches.

### Shorter Search

Inspired by @quasímodo's answer, you can reduce this search a bit to

```
/\d\{1,3}\.\d\{1,3}\.\d\{1,3}\.\d\{1,3}
```

while his answer is definitely the shortest.

### Another Update

@ChristianBrabandt made another good point that the above searches will match ip addresses that are not in the correct address range of 0-255.

His answer is shown below, but in an effort to reduce the expression, we get rid of most of the `\_`'s because they match the end-of-line where we will never see them, and replace a few `[0-9]`'s with `\d`'s:

```
/\(\(25[0-5]\|2[0-4]\d\|[01]\?\d\?\d\)\.\)\{3\}\(25\_[0-5]\|2[0-4]\_[0-9]\|[01]\?\d\?\_[0-9]\)
```

Which yields the following search results: [image: ChristianBrabandt_screenshot_result]

Alas, it looks like some of the entries are still slightly improperly highlighted.

If we specify a space at the start of the match and start the match after that with

```
/\s\zs\(\(25[0-5]\|2[0-4]\d\|[01]\?\d\?\d\)\.\)\{3\}\(25\_[0-5]\|2[0-4]\_[0-9]\|[01]\?\d\?\_[0-9]\)
```

That fixes the bad ip address match of highlighting of 356.3.3.3, but what about the bad 255.255.255.256?  I misused the `\_` and applied it to the ending `\_d`/`\_[0-9]`. It works when adding it to a `\_s` at the end of the expression because we want to match either the end of line or a white space:

```
/\s\zs\(\(25[0-5]\|2[0-4]\d\|[01]\?\d\?\d\)\.\)\{3\}\(25[0-5]\|2[0-4]\d\|[01]\?\d\?\d\_s\)
```

It correctly omits 255.255.255.256:
[image]

Comment: The `.` here is also matching "any character", so this will also match `192a168b0c23` and a range of other stuff that's not really an IP address... That's easily fixable by using `\.` for a literal dot instead.

Comment: Good call @filbranden. I didn't think to check non-ip address cases.  I'll make the edit.

Comment: Note, this also matches something like `1.999.256.500`, which looks like an IPv4 but technically isn't. I have something like this in my VIMRC, (which I don't actually use, but just wanted to remember the pattern): `match ipaddr /\(\(25\_[0-5]\|2\_[0-4]\_[0-9]\|\_[01]\?\_[0-9]\_[0-9]\?\)\.\)\{3\}\(25\_[0-5]\|2\_[0-4]\_[0-9]\|\_[01]\?\_[0-9]\_[0-9]\?\)/` which is a bit more complex

Comment: Another good call @ChristianBrabandt, I'll add it to the answer.